# python to print line from obtained output

Tags: python

- I have a code which is used to print the next word containing in the
  line and it works great

  but i should also need to print the next word **that again contain from the previous output**.
- i tried my coding but not producing expected output

`qwer.txt` contains line by line of:

```
/n i also have a appartment and./n
/nappartment good by the way/n
/nby good  fine/n
/nfine is life/n
/nI have a bike/n
```

**My code**:

```
    for i in cursor.fetchall():
        keywords.append(i[0])
    with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for key in keywords:
                if key in line:
                    line = line.split(" ")
                    print line[line.index(key) + 1]
                    line1 = line[line.index(key) + 1]
                    if line1 in line:
                        print line
```

concept output:in 1rst line: 'appartment' it follows on 2nd line and 2nd line also has 'good' which follows on 3rd line it also has'fine' which is followed by 4th line,but 4th line is not having any word on 5th line.so 5th line should not appear.

Comment: Could you clarify by providing example input and output?

Comment: input is qwer.txt which consists of "i have a car /n car is good /n good is fine /n"

Comment: Are you saying that if ```key``` exists in ```line``` multiple times that you want to print the word just after each ```key``` in ```line```?

Comment: expected output:it must print all the qwer.txt lines provided because all the words output must be previous one so it has to print all lines except last line since last line cannot be previous output..

Comment: @user3647415 "I have a bike"? Does that get output - if so - why?

Comment: no because,in 1rst line: 'appartment' it follows on 2nd line and 2nd line also has 'good' which follows on 3rd line it also has'fine' which is followed by 4th line,but 4th line is not having any word on 5th line.so 5th line should not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `tee` the iterable, then compare each line in pairs to check for word intersections, eg:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
import re

def grouper(iterable):
    fst, snd = tee(iterable)
    next(snd, '')
    for prev, curr in izip(fst, snd):
        if set(re.findall('\w+', prev)).intersection(re.findall('\w+', curr)):
            yield prev

with open('qwer.txt') as fin:
    print list(grouper(fin))

# ['/n i also have a appartment and./n\n', '/nappartment good by the way/n\n', '/nby good  fine/n\n', '/nfine is life/n\n']
```

Then adapt for any specific output you require.

Comment: here it prints only first 2 sentences but good is also on 3rd line because 2nd line consists of only good and so on,i mean it should also  print the 3rd line followed by 4th line.

Comment: @user3647415 well - I just copy/pasted the example data to a text file - and those are the results I get

Comment: yes Jon,It works fine as expected,thank you so much!